# How to import JSQMessagesViewController in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am working with xcode 6.3, swift 1.2 and I install the "JSQMessagesViewController" library with cocoapods. Here is my pod file:

```
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
```

and my bridge file:

```
#import <JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h>
```

then I get the error:

```
'JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
```

I don't know why it goes wrong. When I update the bridge file with

```
 #import "JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h"
```

I get the error

```
JSQMessagesViewController/JSQSystemSoundPlayer+JSQMessages.h:19:9: 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer/JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
```

This really gets me confused because the error is in the source code of JSQMessagesViewController which I cannot modify. I have googled for one day and get no methods to fix it.
   Since the JSQMessagesViewController library is so popular in githup, I believe the there must be someone know how to fix it.

Comment: @jessesquires  Can you explain it for me? Thank you very much!

Comment: same here and no solution for now :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the notation for a framework. Are you using cocoapods 0.36 or later? Then you could make a framework from JSQMessagesViewController by putting this in your pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue and I was using Xcode7, swift 2, iOS 9, using cocoapods version 0.38.2 and what solved it for me was removing the declaration of `#import <JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessages.h>` from the `Bridging-Header.h` file.

Then import it to the class you want to use it in.

```
 import UIKit
 import JSQMessagesViewController

 class MessageViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {

 }
```

As of Cocoapods 0.36 if you put use use_frameworks! into the Podfile (like Eric D said, then cocoapods will create a framework of any Pod that you include.

Comment: This worked for me! The `#import` line was no longer necessary in my bridging header

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
#import "JSQMessages.h"
#import "JSQMessageData.h"
```

*Example taken from [this Swift repo](https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example).*

Comment: I still get the error:/Pods/Headers/Private/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQSystemSoundPlayer+JSQMessages.h:19:9: 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer/JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead

Comment: Did you also install the [sound player](https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example/tree/master/JSQSystemSoundPlayer) with CocoaPods? Looks like it's missing from your install.

Comment: Or maybe the import syntax has to change too, like the other ones: `#import "JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h"`

Comment: CocoaPods installs the JSQSystemSoundPlayer automatically. Add #import "JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h" don't fix the problem. @ericd

Answer (score -1):

For me it worked using this Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
```

And creating the bridge header.

(iOS 9, xCode 7, cocoapods 0.39.0)